# Groovy: extracting strings from space-separated lines

Tags: regex, groovy

So, I got the text file, which basically contains the key/value lines, in each line separated by whitespace.
What I'm trying do achieve is extract value by key, eg. something which in shell is done like this:

```
cat textfile|awk '/item1/ {print $2}'
```

and in groovy something like that does the thing:

```
aa = """
item1 /first/path
item2 /another/path
"""

aa.eachLine {
    m = it =~ /item1\s+(.*)/
    if (m.matches()) {
        println m.group(1)
    }
}
```

But, the question is: how to do that in a nicer/more Groovy way?

regards, Wojtek

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
aa.split( '\n' ).each { 
    def p = it.split(' ')
    if (p.size() == 2) println p[1] 
}
```

Or, with an actual file and allowing many spaces:

```
new File( 'file.txt' ).eachLine {
    def p = it.split(/\s+/)
    if (p.size() == 2) println p[1]
}
```